Right Bracket using `nicematrix` package
Using the nicematrix package, I would like to label rows of a matrix. I have a matrix wherein I would like to highlight two submatrices:

The first three rows are the identity matrix, which I would like to label $\bm{I}_{3 \times 3}$
The last row is a zero row which I would like to label $\bm{O}_{1 \times 3}$.

Here is the closest thing I have so far, which is mostly what I want, but missing the brackets:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for row coloring
   
\begin{document}
    
\begin{align*}
        \bm{R}_0 
        &=
        \begin{bmatrix}[ccc]
            1 &0 &0\\
            0 &0 &0\\
            0 &1 &0\\
            0 &0 &1
        \end{bmatrix} \\
        &=
        \underbrace{
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 &0 &0 &0\\
                0 &0 &0 &1\\
                0 &1 &0 &0\\
                0 &0 &1 &0\\
            \end{bmatrix}
        }_{\bm{P}}
        \begin{bNiceArray}{>{\strut}cccc}% <-- % mandatory
         [margin, extra-margin=2pt,color-inside,no-cell-nodes]
         \rowcolor{blue!15}1 & 0 & 0 \\
         \rowcolor{blue!15}0 & 1 & 0 \\
         \rowcolor{blue!15}0 & 0 & 1 \\
         \rowcolor{red!15}0 & 0 & 0
        \end{bNiceArray}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}

Also, as you can see, my current approach is using bNiceArray because I could not figure out how to accomplish this with bNiceMatrix.
I would like to do something like this, but it does NOT work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for row coloring

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}{>{\strut}cccc}[margin, extra-margin=2pt,color-inside,no-cell-nodes]
    \rowcolor{blue!15}1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor{blue!15}0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \rowcolor{blue!15}0 & 0 & 1 
    \RightBrace[\textstyle I]{3-1}{3-3} \\
    \rowcolor{red!15}0 & 0 & 0 
    \RightBrace[\textstyle O]{4-1}{4-3}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}

The nicematrix documentation has information about \OverBrace and \UnderBrace in section 12.3, on page 39. I could not find any mention of \RightBrace or \LeftBrace, so I am not sure how to accomplish this objective. Please note: I would like to stick with nicematrix if at all possible -- I would rather not resort to TikZ.

Based on F. Pantigny's answer, but putting the labels with the brackets instead of as cells of the matrix works better when you have an even number of rows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
   
\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc}
         \CodeBefore 
           \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{1-1}{3-3}
           \rectanglecolor{red!15}{4-1}{5-3}
         \Body
         \; 1 & 0 & 0 \\
         \; 0 & 1 & 0 \\
         \; 0 & 0 & 1 \\
         \; 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         \; 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         \CodeAfter
            \SubMatrix[{1-1}{5-3}][right-xshift=1.8mm]
            \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{3-3}{{\}\bm{I}_{3\times 3}}}[xshift=3.5mm]
            \SubMatrix{.}{4-1}{5-3}{{\}\bm{O}_{2 \times 3}}}[xshift=3.5mm]
        \end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}



You should use the command \SubMatrix in the \CodeAfter.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
   
\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc}
 \CodeBefore 
   \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{1-1}{3-3}
   \rectanglecolor{red!15}{4-1}{4-3}
 \Body
 \; 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \; 0 & 1 & 0 & &\bm{I}_{3\times 3}\\
 \; 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \; 0 & 0 & 0 & & \bm{0}_{1\times 3}
 \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix[{1-1}{4-3}][right-xshift=1.8mm]
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{3-3}{\}}[xshift=3.5mm]
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}


